# Braces in a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to set up a multiple-images-upload, and I ran across this code:

```
$("<img />", {"src": e.target.result,"class": "thumb-image"}).appendTo($image_holder);
```

The braces seem to settle the arttributes alright for `<img>` tag.

What kind of magic is this ? is there any documentation ? Many thanks.

Comment: This isn't a selector.

Comment: *"is there any documentation?"* - Yes. Of course [there is](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes). All jQuery methods are well documented.

Comment: Documentation link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Comment: same thing:
$('<img />').attr({"src": e.target.result,"class": "thumb-image"}).appendTo($image_holder);

Comment: "Creates DOM elements on the fly...."
Thank you all, it was quick and clear and ~duplicated.